# Slide down div from top then out to the left

Tags: jquery, slide

I am using jQuery.

I need a div to slide down from the top of a page and out to the left.
How can this be done? I am not looking for the slideDown(). I need to div
in it´s whole to slide down from "outside" of the page.

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `animate()`.

Here is a full example. I think you can understand it like it is without extra info:

http://jsfiddle.net/GqN9k/

Comment: Very close! It works perfectly fine the first round animating but the second time it does not slide down, it just appears. Slide to the left works fine every time. This is my code. I have two divs that I am changing between. http://pastie.org/2670551

Comment: I think that's because you are moving quite a distance in 300 ms causing it to look like it just appears. Try decreasing the top the second time or making the animation longer.

Comment: I increased the ms to 3000 but the problem remains. Second time it just pops up (or it feels like it anyway).